# How to write all known time zone names in Objective-C to a file

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get a file which contains, on separate lines, all the time zone names contained in the [knownTimeZoneNames](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimezone/1856138-knowntimezonenames) variable of the `NSTimeZone` class. I'm quite new to Objective-C, though; here is what I've tried so far:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("knownTimeZoneNames.txt", "w+");
    for (NSTimeZone* timezone in [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]) {
        fputs(timezone, fp);    
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the file I get does not seem to be human-readable. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Instead of timezone use timezone.description for `fputs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your string write to file.

```
//Method writes a string to a text file
-(void) writeToTextFile{
        //get the documents directory:
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
            (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt", 
                                                      documentsDirectory];
        //create content - four lines of text
        NSString *content = @"One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive";
        //save content to the documents directory
        [content writeToFile:fileName 
                         atomically:NO 
                               encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
                                      error:nil];

}


//Method retrieves content from documents directory and
//displays it in an alert
-(void) displayContent{
        //get the documents directory:
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                        (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/textfile.txt", 
                                                      documentsDirectory];
        NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName
                                                      usedEncoding:nil
                                                             error:nil];
        //use simple alert from my library (see previous post for details)
        [ASFunctions alert:content];
        [content release];

}
```